# JavaScript returning null on a function for a simple guessing game

Tags: javascript, function, null, typeerror

I created a guessing game using JavaScript. Initially, I wrote it in codepen where it ran fine, and when I moved it over to sublime to test it in the browsers as a standalone, the code did not work. I am getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of null at guess" which is line 14 var guessValue = parseInt(guessIn.value); and links back to the HTML of line 20 which is Guess

I can't figure out where the null is coming from. What am I doing wrong or haven't defined properly that is causing the null? I removed the CSS to blank slate it and make sure that wasn't screwing anything up.

```js
//Generate random number between 1 and 500

var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1);

//Create variables to store info for loops and displaying info back to user
var guessIn = document.getElementById('userGuess');
var guessOut = document.getElementById('guessesMade');
var counter = 0;

//function runs when the guess button is hit

function guess() {
  //declare temp local var and store as an integer for conditional testing
  var guessValue = parseInt(guessIn.value);
  
  //if statement for finding the value and reporting to the user
  //check if the counter is less than 10 and guessValue is not empty
    if (counter < 10 && guessValue) {
      counter++;
    }  
  //the guess is correct
    if (guessValue == randomNumber) {
      guessOut.value = guessOut.value + '\n' + "Guess " + counter + " is " + guessIn.value + ':' + ' You have correctly guessed the number. You may escape.';
    }
  // the guess is greater
    if (guessValue > randomNumber) {
      guessOut.value = guessOut.value + '\n' +"Guess " + counter + " is " + guessIn.value + ':' + ' Your guess is incorrect. The number I am thinking of is lower.';
    }
  //the guess is lower
    if (guessValue < randomNumber) {
      guessOut.value = guessOut.value + '\n' + "Guess " + counter + " is " + guessIn.value + ':' + ' Your guess is incorrect. The number I am thinking of is higher.';
    }
  //when all 10 guesses are used
  else if (counter == 10) {
    guessOut.value = guessOut.value + '\n' + "You did not guess the number I was thinking, " + randomNumber + "." + " You have met your end. Goodbye.";
  }
  return false;
}

//Show the number to guess upon clicking the checkbox for Cheat
function cheat() {
  if (document.getElementById('cheat').checked) {  document.getElementById('cheatNumber').value = randomNumber;
    document.getElementById('cheatShow').style.display = 'inline';
  }
  else {  document.getElementById('cheatNumber').value = '';
 document.getElementById('cheatShow').style.display = 'none';
  }
}

//function to reset the game
function reset() {
  //reset guess value
  userGuess.value = "";
 //reset text area 
  guessesMade.value = "";
  //reset counter
  counter = 0;
  //set new random number for play
  randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 500) + 1);
  return false;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Do You Wanna Play A Game?</title>

<script src="game.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Do You Wanna Play A Game?</h1>
<h3>A Guessing Game</h3>

<fieldset>
 <legend>The Game Starts Now</legend>
 <p>Welcome. You have stumbled upon this page. As a consequence, you have been trapped. To get out, the objective is simple.</p>
  <p>I am thinking of a number. This number is between 1 and 500. You get ten guesses.</p>
 <p>Good luck.</p>

  <div id="guessingarea">
 <input type="text" id="userGuess" value="394" /><br />
  <button onClick="guess();">Guess</button>
  <button onClick="reset();">Reset</button>
    <br />
  <input id="cheat" type="checkbox" value="cheat" onClick="cheat();" />
  <label for="cheat">Cheat</label>
  <div id="cheatShow" style="display: none;">
  <input id="cheatNumber" type="text"/>
  </div>
  </div>
</fieldset>
<p></p>
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Let's examine your guess, shall we?</legend>
    <textarea id="guessesMade"  rows="14" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
  </fieldset>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing any debugging?

Answer (score 0):

You have included the script, before the element is available. As soon as the parser, hits the JS file, it will stop the rendering of the page and try to parse javascript. When the script is encountered, the element is still not available.

You have 2 options to make this work.

Move the script tag to before the close of the `body` element. This will make sure the page has the available elements before manipulating them.

```
     <fieldset>
        <legend>Let's examine your guess, shall we?</legend>
        <textarea id="guessesMade"  rows="14" style="width: 100%;"></textarea>
     </fieldset>

     <script src="game.js"></script>
</body>
```

Query the elements every single time inside the `guess` method since it is only invoked on a click action, which happens only after page is rendered.

```
function guess() {

    var guessIn = document.getElementById('userGuess');
    var guessOut = document.getElementById('guessesMade');

    //declare temp local var and store as an integer for conditional testing
    var guessValue = parseInt(guessIn.value);

    ......
    ......
```

The reason it works on code pen is because, the scripts are executed are deferred to `onLoad` which makes sure the elements are available on the page.

Comment: Thank you! Oh my gosh, so simple and it was driving my crazy!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are including the script before your html document.

```
document.getElementById('userGuess');
```

is called before the element 'userGuess' exists.

I can think of two solutions to this, either include the script at the end of the document, or access this element only when you need it, rather than declaring it at the beginning like so:

```
var guessValue = parseInt(document.getElementById('userGuess').value);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That makes so much sense now that I see it.

Answer (score 0):

If you move the variable declarations inside the function it will work. The issue is that the JavaScript code is executed before the document is ready so the guessIn and guessOut variables are initialised to null.

Alternatively you can wrap your JavaScript code in a function that will execute when the DOM is complete.

```
document.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    // your code goes in here
  }
}
```

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/readyState) for more details.